# Does Thread lock on object ensures lock on member objects too?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Consider following class that I have wrote for testing the locking of non-primitive variable (`myObject`). If all threads are working on same object instance of `SynchronizationTest`, my questions are:

I understand that if thread1 is executing `set(...)` method then any other thread (lets say thread2) is okay to execute either of the `anotherSetWithSynchronized(...)` or `anotherSetWithoutSynchronized(...)`.

1. If thread1 has locked the object of `SynchronizationTest` while executing `set(...)`, does it mean it has acquired lock on all member object variable ? like in this case `myObject`. If not then,
2. If thread1 is executing `set(...)` can thread2 execute `anotherSetWithSynchronized(...)` concurrently?
3. Are none of the two methods can execute simultaneously by thread?
4. Is this design wrong?  Do I need to explicitly lock `myObject` in `synchronized` `set(...)` method. Like this:

   ```
   public synchronized void set(MyValue myValue) {
       synchronized (myObject) {
           myObject.put(myValue);
       }
   }
   ```

Here's my code:

```
public class SynchronizationTest {
  private MyObject myObject = new MyObject();

  public synchronized void set(MyValue myValue) {
    myObject.put(myValue);
  }

  public void anotherSetWithSynchronized(MyValue myValue) {
    synchronized (myObject) {
      myObject.put(myValue);
    }
  }

  public void anotherSetWithoutSynchronized(MyValue myValue) {
    myObject.put(myValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you rewrite question #3?  It is confusing the folks answering.

Answer (score 6):

1: No, set(...) method is guarded by "SynchronizationTest" Object's lock.

2: Yes, their guard objects are different as you've designed.

3: One thread can only run one method per time. If you mean two threads, as I've explained, the methods are guarded by two objects and therefore they can be executed simultaneously

4: Yes, you're right.

---

The intrinsic lock in Java is described as follows in the book "Java Concurrency In Practice":

> A synchronized  block has two parts: a reference to an object that
>   will serve as the lock, and a block of code to be  guarded by that
>   lock. A  synchronized  method is shorthand for a  synchronized  block
>   that spans an entire method  body, and whose lock is the object on
>   which the method is being invoked. (Static  synchronized  methods use
>   the  Class   object for the lock.)

---

For more details, you can refer to section 2.3.1 of "Java concurrency in Practice".

Answer (score 0):

> Does Thread lock on object ensures lock on member objects too?

No.

> I understand that if thread1 is executing set(...) method then any other thread (lets say thread2) is okay to execute either of the anotherSetWithSynchronized

Yes, unless myObject has the same value as 'this'.

Comment: Why is the second one "no" EJP?  Did you misread it?  They are different monitors.  Or are you taking "okay" to mean something other than "can"?

Answer (score 0):

synchronized method is equivalent to

```
public void method(){
   synchronized(this){
      //something
   } 
}
```

1) no

Synchronization is only on specified objects, not on its members.

2) no

3) yes, they cannot, only one thread can be active inside synchronized section guarded by given monitor

4) you don't need to (and you should not use synchronized on method level if you are using explicit synchronization). BUT its better (for libraries/large codebase), because then you can controll who can acces instance on which synchronization occurs, so someone other can't synchronize on it and cause deadlock.

Comment: depends whether he use same instance of SynchronizationTest

Comment: The OP states that he is using the same instance.